# How to import microsoft excel file in to MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, excel

I want to import Microsoft Excel File in to MYSQL table. what can i do for this give me some way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's `,` delimited CSV file; if not you will have to convert it to a CSV file and then you can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) utility to import the data in `MySQL` database.

You should as well check [This Option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html)

Comment: this option is available in microsoft office 2013?

Comment: Not sure, You will have to check it out yourself.